Cookie script runs only once
I am add link in the footer "cookie policy",But Script execute and runs only once launch the popup, I need to launch the pop everytime when i am click on the link.
<div>className="action-label" onClick={() => onCookiePolicyHandler()}>Cookie Policy</div>


onCookiePolicyHandler() {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute(src, xxxx);
  -----Adding Mutilple attributes-----
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}

the above function executes only once launch the popup, when i click on the more than once the script is not showing any popup. Could you please help me on this.


Show the script source. Treat it as a singleton. If the function to show the prefs exists, run it instead of added the script

Most of the cookie banner scripts I've worked with so far, offered explicit JS methods to show their respective popups - have you checked the documentation of the one you are using, for anything like that?

Also, from what you have shown we can't tell, if this xxxx is an additional script you are loading, when this link is clicked - or whether that is supposed to be the "main one" of the whole cookie banner script. If the latter, then only loading it onclick might be fundamentally wrong to begin with - most of these scripts I've encountered, need to be embedded on every page load, for them to be able to work correctly to begin with.



function onCookiePolicyHandler() {
  const existingScript = document.querySelector("script[src='xxxx']");
  if (existingScript) {
    existingScript.remove();
  }

  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'xxxx'; 
  script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
  script.setAttribute('defer', 'true');
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}



The issue here is that adding a  to the DOM will execute it only once. To make it execute every time you click, you'll need to remove the script from the DOM after it's loaded and re-add it when clicked again.

Add an onload event listener to the script to remove it after execution.

Ensure the function creates and appends a new script each time it’s called.

Adding the async and defer attributes will allow the script to load and execute efficiently


